# Why can't I display the next three future events from my model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am attempted to display the next three future events from my database but the code below displays nothing. I can't see what I have done wrong.

This is the event controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @event = Event.where(:slug => params[:slug]).first
    @future_events = Event.where('end_date > ?', Date.today).order('end_date ASC').limit(3)

    General.first.get_blog
    General.first.get_twitter

    if @event.nil?
      @event = Event.first
    end

    @days = [
      { speakers: @event.sessions.day1_speakers, workshops: @event.sessions.day1_workshops },
      { speakers: @event.sessions.day2_speakers, workshops: @event.sessions.day2_workshops }
    ]
  end
end
```

And this is the event view:

```
<% @future_events.first(3).each do |e |  %>
  <div class="fourcol aboutColumn">
    <h3><%= e.title %></h3>
    <p><%= e.start_date.strftime("%e %B %Y") %>, <%= e.venue_title %></p>
    <p><%= e.event_description %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should structure your query to return only the events you need:

```
Event.where('end_date > ?', Date.today).order('end_date ASC').limit(3)
```

Beyond that, I can't see why nothing is displayed. Can you post your entire controller method?

**Update:**

This is the equivalent query for Mongoid:

```
Event.where(:end_date.gt => Date.today).sort(:end_date => 1).limit(3)
```

Comment: I now get this error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1). I have updated the question with the full controller.

Comment: What's the line number or method name associated with the error?

Comment: The error is highlighting line 4, the new code you recommended.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Comment: Rails version 3.2.12, mongoid version 3.0.23

Comment: Dan, I realize now that you included a `mongoid` tag on your question, but I was working from the assumption that you were using ActiveRecord. I've updated my answer with the equivalent Mongoid query.

Comment: Thanks @zach that worked! I thought mongoid might have been the issue :) I forgot to say that I need to exclude the current event from this page so would need to add something like this    unless e.slug.eql? e.slug but can only find ActiveRecord examples on the net.

Comment: You can try chaining a `.not_in(:_id => @event.id)` between the `where` and `sort` calls.

Comment: Thanks again!! That didn't work but this did - ".not_in(:slug => params[:slug])"